# Qual banco de dados devo utilizar em uma aplicação desktop pequena?

Tags: c#, mysql, sql-server, winforms

Li um pouco do Meta e achei que essa pergunta não foge muito das atuais regras do site. Arriscando perder reputação, vamos lá:

No momento trabalho em uma empresa pequena que atualmente, gerencia dados muito sensíveis (documentos, endereços, telefones, etc) pelo Excel, o que geralmente dá muita dor de cabeça (planilhas enormes, dados redundantes, impossibilidade de gerenciar de forma eficiente). Nisso, pensei em fazer um programa pra poder gerenciar esses dados de forma mais hábil.

Escolhi C# como linguagem de programação e Windows Forms (é uma aplicação interna - então não tem necessidade de ser "bonita" - e eu tenho atualmente mais facilidade com Windows Forms) mas estou com algumas duvidas cruéis no banco de dados:

1. Como é uma aplicação .NET, utilizar MySQL ainda é uma boa opção ou SQL Server é mais seguro, em questão da integração do banco de dados com o resto do projeto (talvez o MySQL tenha alguns problemas com .NET?)?
2. Primeiramente escolhi configurar um servidor local no escritório, e deixar a aplicação no notebook, deixando o desktop exclusivo para ser o banco de dados. Porém, alguém pode ver isso como "desperdício de recursos" (deixar o computador parado e ligado sem "utilizar"). Seria seguro deixar ele produtivo (com uma pessoa utilizando pra ler emails, acessar a internet, etc) e ao mesmo tempo guardar os dados da aplicação? Ou devo isola-lo para ser apenas guardar os dados?
3. Também pensei em utilizar um VPS para guardar os dados, fazendo possível utilizar o programa em outros lugares (o que pode ser útil). Porém, eu teria que proteger o banco de dados contra ataques que não seriam necessários se o banco fosse local (se fosse local alguém poderia roubar o computador com os dados, mas aí é outra história). É mais viavel investir um pouco em deixar os dados na nuvem ou ser mais seguro e deixar localmente?
4. Eu talvez esteja sendo muito exagerado. Também seria possível guardar os dados junto com a aplicação, ao invés de configurar um servidor só para isso. Porém, acho isso um tanto quanto errado e inseguro, mas posso estar errado.

Sobre os dados do projeto: São documentos brasileiros (RG e CPF), telefone, email, endereço e nome completo. Não é uma empresa tão high-profile a ponto de utilizar criptografia "pesada", mas não posso me permitir que isso fique desprotegido.

Uma informação que não lembrava antes de colocar aqui foi a opinião de alguns que perguntei em outros lugares, que foi que eu estou exagerando e deveria permanecer no Excel pra evitar complicar mais as coisas. Discordo disso pois já ocorreu muito transtorno com esses dados sendo guardados de maneira inadequada, mas talvez exista alguma outra abordagem que eu possa tomar que eu não esteja vendo.

É uma duvida que está me impedindo de iniciar a produção do projeto. Discuti com algumas pessoas e não cheguei em um consenso. Qual seria a melhor ação a se tomar nesse caso?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Uma vez que não se trata de uma pergunta do tipo "qual banco de dados é melhor" em absoluto, mas sim uma do tipo "como posso resolver o um problema" (e um problema bem comum), acho que a pergunta é válida.

Dito isso:

> - Como é uma aplicação .NET, utilizar MySQL ainda é uma boa opção ou SQL Server é mais seguro?

Tanto MySql quanto SQL Server podem servir bem ao teu propósito. Eu recomendo SQL Server apenas porque é mais fácil de integrar com aplicações .NET. Se você fosse trabalhar com PHP ou Ruby, eu recomendaria MySql.

O SQL Server tem uma edição Express que é gratuita. Ela tem algumas limitações como utilizar no máximo uma certa quantidade de memória e de recursos do processador, mas para o seu caso, acredito que isso não seria problema. Se as limitações do SQL Server Express forem um problema, então você não vai conseguir resolver os problemas da sua empresa apenas com uma aplicação do tipo que você se propõe a fazer ;)

> Primeiramente escolhi configurar um servidor local no escritório, e deixar a aplicação no notebook, deixando o desktop exclusivo para ser o banco de dados.

Vocês podem também pagar 5 dólares por mês pra hospedar um banco de dados em qualquer buraco da Internet (desculpe a expressão, mas é para dar ênfase à banalidade da coisa). Dessa forma vocês não vão perder todo o banco de dados quando a máquina quebrar.

> Porém, alguém pode ver isso como "desperdício de recursos" (deixar o computador parado e ligado sem "utilizar").

Da próxima vez que alguém levantar esse argumento, pergunte a pessoa quanto custa manter um computador ligado durante o expediente. Veja o impacto na conta de energia e se surpreenda o quanto isso é barato.

> Seria seguro deixar ele produtivo (com uma pessoa utilizando pra ler emails, acessar a internet, etc) e ao mesmo tempo guardar os dados da aplicação? Ou devo isola-lo para ser apenas guardar os dados?

Você vai apenas substituir Excel, e não fazer nada tão complicado quanto análise de material genético ou de padrões do clima, certo? Pode rodar tranquilo numa máquina comum enquanto a secretária <strike>passa o dia no Facebook</strike> trabalha no computador. Contanto que seja mesmo uma máquina comum, e não uma carroça (por exemplo, algo com dois gigabytes de RAM ou menos, para os padrões atuais).

> Também pensei em utilizar um VPS para guardar os dados, fazendo possível utilizar o programa em outros lugares (o que pode ser útil). Porém, eu teria que proteger o banco de dados contra ataques que não seriam necessários se o banco fosse local (se fosse local alguém poderia roubar o computador com os dados, mas aí é outra história). É mais viavel investir um pouco em deixar os dados na nuvem ou ser mais seguro e deixar localmente?

Utilizar um bom esquema de autenticação e guardar o hash salgado das senhas deve ser suficiente para proteger todos os segredos industriais da pesquisa militar feita para o DARPA que sua empresa guarda no Excel ;)

> Eu talvez esteja sendo muito exagerado. Também seria possível guardar os dados junto com a aplicação, ao invés de configurar um servidor só para isso. Porém, acho isso um tanto quanto errado e inseguro, mas posso estar errado.

Se você quis dizer que pode rodar a aplicação na mesma máquina que o banco, tudo bem. Se você quis dizer guardar as informações em um formato próprio da aplicação e dispensar o banco, não, você não está errado.

**edição:** o Excel tem formas de permitir trabalho em grupo em cima da mesma planilha. Todas as alterações são mescladas em tempo real. Se você quer manter as coisas simples, talvez isso ajude. Mas um banco de dados permite que a informação seja melhor organizada e consultada de forma mais rápida, então recomendo que continue buscando uma solução com banco de dados.

Comment: Não consegui entender se você prefere um banco local ou na nuvem. Deu a entender outra coisa.

Sobre criptografia: Eu quis dizer que, atualmente, desconheço completamente o assunto. Minha pergunta foi se vale a pena colocar na nuvem e investir um tempo para aprender (inevitavelmente terei que fazer isso, mas pode atrasar a aplicação atual) ou deixar os dados localmente para evitar transtornos em relação a isso.

Comment: "Nuvem" é uma *buzzword*. Toda empresa que faz *hosting* utiliza esse termo hoje em dia. Quando digo "pagar cinco dólares para hospedar" é a isso que me refiro. E você não precisa aprender muito mais - para a sua aplicação, tanto faz se ela vai se conectar a um banco local ou a um banco "na nuvem". Seu código vai ser o mesmo. O único esforço extra que você vai ter é verificar se o firewall permite conexão com o servidor de banco de dados que está "na nuvem".

Answer (score 8):

1. O importante é o acesso físico à base de dados, pois a meu ver tanto o SqlServer quanto o MySql são seguros do ponto de vista de acesso via rede.
2. Depende do requisito de confidencialidade das informações que você vai guardar neste sistema. Mas a princípio sim, seria seguro, mas para ter mais certeza tem que te haver uma deliberação da importancia das informações dentro do sistema.
3. Dependendo dos tipos de dados, talvez seja necessário deixá-lo em solo brasileiro. Lembro-me de um professor contar que por exemplo o Serasa usa cloud nas aplicações mas a base de dados fica no Brasil por motivos jurídicos.
4. É possível sim guardar de forma segura os dados no próprio computador que vai usá-los. Pode começar com acessos via GRANT nas tabelas do banco de dados. É um caminho...

Sugerindo uma base, eu sugeriria o firebird ou o sqlite, o sqlite tem um modelo de dados um pouco mais flexível que o firebird, isso pode ser bom ou ruim, mas creio que o mundo .NET esteja mais acostumado com o firebird.

Answer (score 4):

Me permita responder **apenas o ponto 2**. Não vou falar sobre os demais pontos pois não tenho muita autoridade em todos eles. Mas na parte de infraestrutura de servidores eu tenho :)

O ideal sempre é **dedicar o servidor**. Não é uma boa prática deixar usuários no computador que é o próprio servidor. O uso não condiz com o nível crítico do servidor pois ele contém a vida da empresa.

Se alguém achar que é desperdício de recurso, imagine o desperdício que seria perder todos os dados. Mesmo que tenha *backup* para recuperar, o tempo gasto geralmente não vale a pena. Além de você como administrador perder credibilidade na empresa e a empresa perder credibilidade com os clientes caso isso os afete (por menor que seja o dano ao cliente).

Answer (score 4):

Como me parece que a empresa está procurando uma solução que seja barata, e que não desperdice muitos recursos, talvez uma opção seja usar um shared-hosting voltado para .Net, e criar uma aplicação Web ao invés de desktop (eu sei que isso vai contra a sua opção de usar windows forms, mas acredite, é uma vantagem imensa).

Então quais são as vantagens:

- as pessoas podem acessar os dados de qualquer lugar
- baixo custo, um shared-host bom para .Net custa US$ 10
- existem planos com backup dos dados (mesmo por esse preço)
- não ter de lidar com a parte de infraestrutura
- quando a empresa estiver disposta, pode migrar facilmente para um host dedicado, ou mesmo para um host interno (i.e. intranet)

Desvantagens dessa aboradagem:

- você terá de usar uma tecnologia com a qual não está familiarizado (escolha ASP.NET MVC se for o caso)
- você terá de se preocupar mais com a segurança lógica dos dados (terá de fazer um login, e provavelmente usar HTTPS e obter um certificado de fonte confiável, o que terá um custo inicial)
- os dados não estarão totalmente seguros, uma vez que armazenados num shared-host
- a conexão com a internet se torna uma necessidade

Nota: no Visual Studio é possível já criar uma aplicação MVC que vem de exemplo, com recursos como login e cadastro de dados, basta usar como modelo.

Sobre o banco de dados, usaria o SQL Server mesmo. Os planos de shared-host geralmente oferecem um banco pelo menos, que para uma aplicação pequena servem bem.

Comment: `existem planos com backup dos dados (mesmo por esse preço)` fuja de planos que não oferecem backup! Ademais, +1.

Comment: não descartei fazer algo pra web ao invés de desktop (caso eu fizesse isso, tentaria fugir do .NET), mas não consolidei porque é uma área que conheço pouco e exige um tempo maior pra aprender do que já usar winforms que eu já tive um contato anterior, o que iria atrasar o projeto. também pensei que seria melhor, pensando em mim como profissional, explorar mais o winforms antes de ir para outras terras. é uma abordagem que me senti mais "seguro" em seguir, mas talvez eu esteja vendo de forma errônea

Comment: Porque fugir do .Net? É uma tecnologia totalmente estabelecida, com amplo suporte, uma imensa comunidade de desenvolvedores... não vejo porque fugir.

Answer (score 3):

Você disse que guarda dados sensíveis em excel?

Para dados sensíveis e C# eu preferiria usar o MS Sql.
Para dados não tão importantes você pode usar qualquer um. bases "menores" (com certeza sua base é pequena) podem usar o MySql que hoje em dia está bem robusto.
(IMHO uma base pequena tem menos de uma gigabyte e uma grande tem mais de um terabyte).

Sua maior insegurança é ter os dados num notebook, ele pode quebrar, ser roubado, etc.
O certo seria te-los num servidor e por segurança servidores nem deveriam ter navegadores ou ferramentas para ler emails, independente to RDBMS usado.

Por último mas não menos importante. Agregar valor. Você vai ganhar experiência numa base de dados, vai trabalhar meses, anos com ela.

Qual você quer aprender? MySql ou MS-Sql. No caso de agregar valor a você como profissional eu escolheria o MS-Sql.

Comment: Sobre tamanho: existem em uma média bem por alto, umas 200 pessoas "cadastradas". Os dados são telefone, email, CPF, RG, nome completo e endereço. Não tenho ideia de comparação pra determinar o "tamanho" do (futuro?) banco de dados.

Não entendi a comparação que você fez de começo. Porque o MySQL seria para "dados não tão importantes"?

Comment: Talvez não tenha me expressado bem. O MySql tem capacidade sim de persistir dados sensíveis. Quanto ao tamanho, uma base pode ser condierada grande apartir de um terabyte.

Answer (score 2):

Creio que pela linguagem que foi escolhida e se o volume de dados que essa aplicação irá gerenciar , utilize um SGBD ligado ao C#, o próprio SQLServer Express. Agora , por maior facilidade e confiabilidade , creio que o Mysql é uma boa escolha de SGBD.